# Can not move custom UIView on storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, custom-view

I have created custom UIView

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class CategoryIcon: UIView {
let pi:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

@IBInspectable var circleColor:UIColor = UIColor.green
@IBInspectable var width:CGFloat = 10
@IBInspectable var radius: CGFloat = 20

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 ,y:bounds.height/2)
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    path.lineWidth = width
    circleColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

}

}
```

But when I add it to the storyboard does not matter where i put it it stay at the left top corner of parent view [as you can see dots shows that view has moved but drawings are out of view and at the left top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CulQg.png)

what is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Are you trying to say that no matter where you try to put the view it always is in the same position? Or does the position change as you try to change the position.

Comment: @joshLor it always stays at the left top part of parent view wherever i move it. but the thing is if you look at link I provided in post 8 dots representing bounds  of view shows that it has moved, in fact what I have draw stays out of UIView at the top left of parent view

Comment: can you show how you are implementing it in the viewcontroller ?

Comment: 2 question: 1. do you have code in your view that you are not showing there also. 2. Is center a keyword? As I have never used your method of implementing paths.

Comment: @joshLor no, center is from previous part when I was trying to draw circle with arc. That all the code I have for UIView I do nothing else in side or outside class.

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad all the code I have is in post. If you ask about Parent View controller here it is https://pastebin.com/J4PNmZb5 . But it does not have anything to do with UIView for now

Comment: where are you using this categoryicon ?

Comment: Where are you trying to change the position then?

Comment: @joshLor when I move the UIView on storyboard.

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad I added it to the left side of UITableViewCell

Comment: do you have constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the following line from your `draw(rect:)` method:

```
    center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 ,y:bounds.height/2)
```

It's generally inadvisable to change a view's state while executing drawing code. But in this particular case, you're changing the location of the view's `frame` based on the origin of its `bounds`, which is ordinarily **(0, 0)**, unless you've modified the bounds elsewhere. It's not clear what you were hoping to accomplish by doing that, but what it actually does is move the view to the upper left corner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thing is I was initialy drawing with arcs and in this case I was using center. Then when i switched to ovals i did not delete it. Somehow missed it. Thanks for helping.